# materialized view with column from previous refresh

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I have a materialized view that calculates the rank of a score column every month for a monthly ranking table. I want to have an extra column that contains the previous month's ranking as well so that I can show which items dropped and which rose. What's the best way to go about doing that?

Obviously this doesn't work

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW public.monthlyranking
TABLESPACE pg_default
AS SELECT s.id,
          rank() OVER (ORDER BY s.score DESC) AS ranking,
          m.ranking AS ranking_old
   FROM scorelist s
    LEFT JOIN monthlyranking m ON m.id = s.id
WITH DATA;
```

Comment: for me the best way to do it is to create a new table and to store the rank by month. You could then retrieve the datas as expected and compare with the previous month